# Using NFS with Dask workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have been experimenting with using an NFS shared drive with my user and Dask workers. Is this something that can work? I noticed that Dask created two files in my home directory, global.lock and purge.lock, and did not clean them up when workers were finished. What do these files do?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely normal to use the NFS to host a user's software environment.  The files you're seeing are used by a different system altogether.

When Dask workers run out of space they spill excess data to disk.  An NFS *can* work here, but it's much nicer to use local disk if available.  This is usually configurable with the `--local-directory` dask-worker keyword, or the temporary-directory configuration value.

You can read more about storage issues with NFS and more guidelines here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/hpc.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer @mrocklin. I thought it might be helpful, or in some cases just easier, to share data with workers by having a shared filesystem. Also it might be easier to modify the worker environment using locally installed packages. I will continue to test this with my current setup. But from the sound of these answers it seems that these lock files are not meant to lock the filesystem for a particular worker so it could potentially work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dask can be used with an NFS mound, and indeed you can share configuration/scheduler state between the various processes. Each worker process will use its own temporary storage area. The lock files are safe to ignore, and their existence will depend on exactly the workload you are doing.

Comment: Okay thank you for this input @mdurant. I will continue to test this and see if it will work with my workflow.